# Plotly : AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Here it is about an AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'. Although the part of code was from plotly docs.

Can someone please help me on this plotly subplot error: This was used to run but now it throws an error? I don't get it.

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
fig = make_subplots(rows=2)
Tech = data2.Technologie.unique()

import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.validators.scatter.marker import SymbolValidator

raw_symbols = SymbolValidator().values
namestems = []
namevariants = []
symbols = []
for i in range(0,len(raw_symbols),2):
    name = raw_symbols[i+1]
    symbols.append(raw_symbols[i])
    namestems.append(name.replace("-open", "").replace("-dot", ""))
    namevariants.append(name[len(namestems[-1]):])

#fig = make_subplots(subplot_titles=("Demand"))

#range_y =[1200, 1800]
#Lignite1, Gas1, Hardcoal1, Demand1, PV1, Wind_Onshore1, Wind_Offshore1, Lit_Ion1, PSH1
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-4-06419481b94d> in <module>
     23     name = raw_symbols[i+1]
     24     symbols.append(raw_symbols[i])
---> 25     namestems.append(name.replace("-open", "").replace("-dot", ""))
     26     namevariants.append(name[len(namestems[-1]):])
     27 

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Comment: try name = str(raw_symbols[i+1])

Comment: What datatype values does `raw_symbols []` have? ? If it has only `string`'s you can use `replace()` but even if it has one `int` then you can't do that!